# How htlatex decides which equations needs to convert as images and math

Tags: equations, tex4ht, inline, type

I have given simple code below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

This is for test $-3$ inline equation $-z a-3\sqrt[2]{a+b}$

\end{document}
```

Then I run the command `htlatex test "xhtml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate-p"`, it converts the first display equation as `HTML` tag and the second inline upto `\sqrt`, it converts as `HTML` tags and the remaining as image, check the image attached:

[image]

And the converted HTML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="test.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2017-08-04 15:23:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >This is for test <span 
class="cmsy-10">&#x2212;</span>3 inline equation <span 
class="cmsy-10">&#x2212;</span><span 
class="cmmi-10">za </span><span 
class="cmsy-10">&#x2212; </span>3<img 
src="test0x.png" alt="&#x221A; -----
2 a+ b"  class="root" align="middle"  />
</p>

</body></html>
```

Can you please advise me how htlatex decides which part should treat as images and which as HTML tags?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, content which can't be easily displayed using HTML is converted to images by default. This is the case of `\sqrt` of `\frac`, for example. Basic characters and numbers can be converted as HTML. Note also that display math is always converted.

You can use `pic-m` command line option to request conversion of inline math to images. Ideally, together with `svg` option, which will use SVG instead of bitmap images, it looks much better. Best option is of course to not use picture math at all, but use `mathml` and MathJax rendering.